# Log4j - disabling logs for a package

Tags: java, spring, logging

How do I disable logs for a specific package when I  manually create the Appenders in a Java Class.I know that in the properties file,specifying log4j.logger.org.springframework=OFF would disable logs coming from the spring framework package.But I am not sure as to how this can be done from a Java class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

For a specific package (instead of a specific class):

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("my.package.name");
logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: Thanks.But this will disable all the logs correct?If I want to restrict logs from a package from being written how do I do that?

Comment: Updated. I'd also suggest trying it to see what results you get, and updating your question accordingly.